# Solutions for connecting phone/tablet to a bigger monitor?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, external-display

An ebook I purchased is locked to my device so I can't open it anywhere else. I'm having a hard time reading due to the small screen size of my phone.

Is there a way I can get it to display on my monitor? I don't have any special cables so I'll have to use any wireless means possible. Also to note: I'm not looking for emulation as the app has locked my ebook to the device.

Any creative solutions are welcome.

Comment: Not an aswer to your question but you can transfer an ebook if the other device is registered with the same ID: Content Portability http://www.adobe.com/solutions/ebook/digital-editions/faq.html

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the MHL Adapter Cable.

[image]

From the MHL Adapter, you can connect to any TV that support HDMI.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about sharing your phone's screen on computer? Lot of apps and tweaks are available on the Internet. Few such results I found quickly by searching are [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G1Wc4uYydD4) and [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_rS2ly9fk-Q) video and a [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1653080) page.  I am unable to provide more specific answer as I am not aware of your phone's software version and its hardware capabilities.  As @Jack said, if you have HDMI out it will be the best option.

By seeing your phone's screen on the computer, you would be running the eBook reader app in the phone but read the book in your monitor.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the Android version, you may be able to "[Miracast](http://www.zdnet.com/projecting-your-pc-or-mobile-device-with-miracast-how-well-does-it-work-7000031929/)"  screen cast to an external Miracast receiver.

It's a wireless solution.

An [introduction](http://www.cnet.com/how-to/miracast-everything-to-know-about-mirroring-android/) with a video.