# How could I view that Android Screen on a computer or larger screen

Tags: external-display

How can I display my Android ICS Samsung Galxy S3 Screen on a Laptop or Monitor Screen? Are there any fast quick programs which do this?

Comment: Related questions: [Solutions for connecting phone/tablet to a bigger monitor?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/40706), [How do I project the screen of my android phone for a presentation?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/5652), [How can I view my phone's screen on a computer in real time?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/20199)

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts, Anton! Have you tried clicking on the tags you've just assigned to your question? the `external-display` seems like a good candidate -- and true, in its [most frequented questions](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/external-display?sort=faq) it turns up e.g. [Can I connect an Android phone to an external monitor, keyboard and mouse?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/4546/16575) -- which sounds quite promising :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are lot of apps to do that. One is droid@screen; you need to have access to Android development toolkit for that though.

Extremely sorry for not providing the links, here are the links

droid@screen http://droid-at-screen.ribomation.com/ please install the USB drivers of you phone, instructions about how to use it is given there on the site.

If it asks for ADB you need to download Android SDK from here http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html (Got to other platforms, download SDK. ) ADB will be present in platforms tools inside the SDK

Comment: Parry, a beginner might look helpless at your "one-liner". Mind to explain it with some more words? (and no, the downvote is not mine ;)

Comment: If possible, please also provide a link to the app.

Comment: @all added the links to original reply

Comment: I vouch for droid at screen, you can even show 2 connected phones at the same time!

Answer (score 2):

Well, recently Teamviewer came out with something called Teamviewer QuickSupport...

For your android device, go to

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teamviewer.quicksupport.market.samsung&hl=en

then download it onto your android. then go to www.teamviewer.com, download teamviewer, install it for free use, and then create an account. then, on your android, click on the quicksupport app. it will open and give you a number. open teamviewer and type in that number. it will connect. voila!

Answer (score 2):

I use cable from galaxy's audio jack to projectors video input...

Comment: From the *audio* jack to the projector's *video* input? How does that work?

Comment: How do you do that?! Please explain

Comment: Some older phones support connecting a 3.5mm video out plug to the headphone jack, which gives an RCA connection. See [this article](http://androidandme.com/2010/07/news/samsung-galaxy-s-does-video-out-via-3-5-mm-headset-jack/) for an example using Galaxy S. But as far as I know, newer phones like the S3 don't support this anymore, only digital AV out over MHL.

Answer (score 2):

I use [Screen Stream](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobzapp.screenstream.trial). It sends my screen to VLC.

I am happy with it.

Answer (score -1):

I Use A/V cable connected from android jack out and tv in

Comment: With a Galaxy S3? Most of the newer phones only support digital video out via MHL, not analog video out like the older models.